# How to upgrade cakephp from 1.3 to 2.1?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I'm a newbie in cakephp, I'm trying to upgrade cakephp to the latest version.
I install the fresh cakephp 1.3 on my computer and the upgrade it to cakephp 2.1.

I use shell to upgrade, but after I run 'upgrade all' command, I saw two error:

> `Warning Error: chmod(): Operation not permitted in [/var/www/cakephp-1.3/lib/Cake/Utility/Folder.php, line 639]`
>
> `Warning Error: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted in [/var/www/cakephp-1.3/lib/Cake/Utility/Folder.php, line 640]`

I think it has upgraded complete. Because I see the message from terminal like this:

> Done updating /var/www/cakephp-1.3/app/Console/cake.php
>
> Done updating /var/www/cakephp-1.3/app/Console/Command/AppShell.php
>
> Running components
>
> Running exceptions

Then I refresh my app and I got some errors:
http://flic.kr/p/bwUpwY

Then I delete 'cake' directory, and the error message has changed:
http://flic.kr/p/bKP7Te

So now I don't know what to do next, because I did many ways but still not make it work.
So anybody please tell me what I did wrong and how can I upgrade cakephp successful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you install CakePHP 1.3 first?

Comment: Because I have a web application which using cakephp 1.3 and I want to upgrade it. But I want to practice on the fresh install first.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have permissions issues on some of the directories that the CakePHP migration script expects to be writable.

This could lead to the migration failing on some parts and leaving a partially broken install after it completes.